# C# Swap folder name

Tags: c#

newbie here. Currently I want to swap 2 file name(_newPostTicket to _PostTicket).
_newPostTicket and _PostTicket are .txt file.

Below is the content of txt file.

```
# start time = 2021-12-03-15-14-55

# end time = 2021-12-03-15-15-41

# name = SYSTEM

bot 10 pad 11 d 4 e 6 t #0 0 2021-12-03-15-14-55 # - 2021-12-03-15-15-41

bot 11 pad 12 d 5 e 7 t #0 0 2021-12-03-15-14-55 # - 2021-12-03-15-15-41

bot 12 pad 13 d 6 e 8 t #0 1 2021-12-03-15-14-55 # - 2021-12-03-15-15-41

and more
```

And below is the code.

```
DirectoryInfo srcDir = new DirectoryInfo(srcDataFolderPath);
string srcDataFolderPath = Path.Combine(DataSource, folderName);
string PostTicketPath = srcDataFolderPath + _POSTTICKET;
string newPostTicketPath = srcDataFolderPath + _newPOSTTICKET;
string tempPostTicketPath = srcDataFolderPath + _tempPOSTTICKET;


if (srcDir.Exists == true)
{
    if ((File.Exists(PostTicketPath)) &&(File.Exists(srcDataFolderPath + _PRETICKET)))
    {
        using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(newPostTicketPath))
        {
            foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(PostTicketPath))
            {
                string[] getFromLine = line.Split(' ');
                if (getFromLine.Length >= 11 && getFromLine[0] != "#" && getFromLine[10] == "0")
                {
                    getFromLine[10] = "3";
                    sr.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", getFromLine));
                }
                else
                {
                    sr.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    File.Move(newPostTicketPath, tempPostTicketPath);
    File.Move(PostTicketPath, newPostTicketPath);
    File.Move(tempPostTicketPath, PostTicketPath);
}
```

I try run and it can generate a _newPostTicket and also success to swap _newPostTicket and _PostTicket.

But it will also generate the _newPostTicket at directory with _PostTicket that do not have getFromLine[10] == "0".

How can only generate newPOSTTICKET at directory with _PostTicket that got getFromLine[10] == "0" and swap the name. Anyone got better idea?

Thanks

Comment: You ultimately want to swap the names of 2 files. Am I right?

Comment: you can check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

##### Swapping the file names in C#:

```
    string path = @"C:\Users\Public\Documents\";
    string _PostTicket = "PostTicket.txt";
    string _newPostTicket = "newPostTicket.txt";

    string _PostTicketPath = Path.Combine(path, _PostTicket);
    string _newPostTicketPath = Path.Combine(path, _newPostTicket);

    if (File.Exists(_PostTicketPath) && File.Exists(_newPostTicketPath))
    {
        File.Move(_PostTicketPath, _PostTicketPath + ".bak");
        File.Move(_newPostTicketPath, _PostTicketPath);
        File.Move(_PostTicketPath + ".bak", _newPostTicketPath);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File does not exist");
    }
```

##### Works fine.